# JQueryUI - Resizable forcing my div to switch from Position:Relative to Absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to create a sliding, resizable bar inside a container.  For some reason, the resizable method is converting the div from Position:Relative to Position:Absolute.  This is then visually moving the box, and ruining the scroll action of the containers' container.

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/thalladay/m7Yv4/)

I have tried hooking into the Stop and Resize event and converting back to Position:Relative, but it's quite a hack, and the results are not perfect.  It seems like this should just work?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Timeline").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent"
    })
    .resizable({
        containment: "parent",
        handles: 'e, w'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 800px; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="TimelineCanvas">
        <div class="TimelineContainer">
            <div class="Timeline">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
#TimelineCanvas
{
    width: 2000px;
    height: 150px;
}
.TimelineContainer
{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.Timeline
{
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: Gray;
    cursor: move;
}
```

My best attempt at a fix so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Timeline").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent"
    })
    .resizable({
        containment: "parent",
        handles: 'e, w',
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css("height", '');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css("position", '');
            $(this).css("top", '');
            $(this).css("height", '');
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated;  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the original defect report for why it happened, but it's pretty clearly intentional, quite possibly browser-specific... A dirty solution may be the best you have.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js#L242

```
  // bugfix for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1749
  if (el.is('.ui-draggable') || (/absolute/).test(el.css('position'))) {
      el.css({position: 'absolute',top: iniPos.top,left: iniPos.left});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
.resizable({
        grid: 25,
        containment: "#"+ $(this).parent().attr("id"), // The parent
        stop: function(e, $this) {
            $(this).css({
                position: "relative",
                left: $this.originalPosition.left,
                width:$this.originalSize.width
            });
        }
    })
```

That should be `the right way` to do it. But certainly is not (always something would be broken because `draggable` and `re sizable` have a position-width-conflict), we must wait for Jquery-ui 2.0...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [original jQuery UI ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/1749) and an updated link.  The ticket referenced in the code is incorrect.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js#L299

```
// bugfix for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1749
if ( (/absolute/).test( el.css("position") ) ) {
    el.css({ position: "absolute", top: el.css("top"), left: el.css("left") });
} else if (el.is(".ui-draggable")) {
    el.css({ position: "absolute", top: iniPos.top, left: iniPos.left });
}
```

Comment: These tickets provide a litte more insight: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5335 http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6939

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position property of your resizable object to !important